# Kerberos: ticket with no REALM after principal name (i.e. `principal@`)

Tags: networking, active-directory, domain-controller, kerberos

When I run a `klist` after ssh-ing into a Kerberized instance, I obtain the TGS for the principal `host/vmtest001`, however, why do I get two of them including one with no REALM after the `@` separator?

Here is the output of `klist`:

```
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1000
Default principal: athena@EXAMPLE.COM

Valid starting     Expires            Service principal
06/13/21 21:05:00  06/14/21 07:05:00  krbtgt/EXAMPLE.COM@EXAMPLE.COM
        renew until 06/14/21 21:04:59
06/13/21 21:05:03  06/14/21 07:05:00  host/vmtest001@
        renew until 06/14/21 21:04:59
06/13/21 21:05:03  06/14/21 07:05:00  host/vmtest001@EXAMPLE.COM
        renew until 06/14/21 21:04:59
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your `/etc/krb5.conf` to explicity define the realm's domain:

```
[domain_realm]
    .example.com = EXAMPLE.COM
    example.com = EXAMPLE.COM
```

Comment: I would love to know what is going on here.